# Tool to make ERD for PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, erd

I am looking for a tool with that I can create a database ERD for a PostgreSQL Database.

In MySQL I use the tool "MySQL Workbench"

Do you know such a tool with that i can create a ERD. And from the ERD automatical create a sql-skript.

BG

Comment: @ALL is there any add-on for pgadmin III  to get the ER-Diagrams done as this [Video in this Link Says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692913/create-an-er-diagram-in-pgadmin) for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use DbWrench and Aqua Data Studio most often for these. There are many.  See also:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

DbWrench also has a handy reverse synchronize, which allows you to compare a model with changes made on the server.

If you mean that you want to dump the schema as is, I would definitely use pg_dump --schema rather than going through a GUI.

If you mean that you want to modify the schema, then I most tools will support that.

I have no association with DbWrench or ADS.

Answer (score 0):

[RISE](http://www.risetobloome.com/Page_1_S_NoPadding.aspx?item=530) is a freeware application that can model ERDs and even propagate it into the database layer.

Comment: thank you for the answer.

When i push the Generate code to file button, i Can generate a skript for Postgresql but when i run it, there are more tables in my database.
and the names of the tables are much longer...

Comment: I'm not very fluent in RISE, however, this seems to be a problem with RISE itself. It should be able to do what you want it to do. Maybe post another question for RISE?

Comment: Looks like RISE neither supports PG specific or derived data types, e.g., money, geometry, nor allows for customization. Also I'm not sure whether it allows for inheritance / partitioning.