# How to visualize database tables in postgresql using pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to visualize tables and their relations using pgAdmin. I have understood that there is a [query visualizer tool](http://link.sheidaei.com/byqyv) available for pgAdmin. However, that only is useful if you are dealing with queries. My main goal is to generate a graphical representation of all the tables available in database.

Comment: are you trying to extract an ERD ?

Comment: @amphibient Any visualization; if I can generate ERD that's even better.

Comment: can you use Visio for that, if you have it ?

Comment: or this http://www.smartdraw.com/specials/erddataflow.asp

Comment: I have found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694261/892535 I am using pgAdmin 1.16 but can't see database designer tool.

Comment: There you go everything is explained here

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16993/how-to-view-data-in-pgadmin-iii

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have found [this webpage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) on postgresql wiki, with various tools on utilizing a postgresql database. I have used DbWrench on Mac to generate the ERD.

Answer (score 84):

In pgAdmin 4 right click on the database and then "Generate ERD (Beta)"

[image]

Comment: not in Beta anymore, i mean is just 'Generate ERD now', worked fine, thanks!

Comment: How to do this for just an individual table and its relatives?

Answer (score 21):

For pgadmin 3
Go to Tools -> Query Tool

Graphical Query Builder is a tab in the Query Tool view.

unfortunately Pgadmin 4 does not have this option.

Comment: Hello, where is the tab for the Graphical Query Builder? I have the query tool, but then the options within it are no tabs gall GQB. Where can i find this tool?

Comment: pgAdmin removed this feature in newer versions, sadly.

Comment: in pgAdmin 4 right click on database -> Generate ERD (Beta)

Answer (score 6):

try pgModeler - there is working demo (although limited by number of objects). Also only PostgreSQL 9.x is supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JetBrains DataGrip for visualize your database schemas. Create a connection to DB, and right click on [shema name] -> Diagrams -> Show visualisation.

Comment: For big companys only: not "free of charge".