# How to get a DataBase Design for POSTGRESQL to create a ER-Diagram?

Tags: postgresql, reverse-engineering, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin, phppgadmin

I am using **postgresql 9.2**

```
postgres=# select version();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

and **pgadmin III**

I have a database with tables which have one-to-many & many-to-one relationships.

I want to make ER diagrams, i.e., a database design of the tables.

I have searched and referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692913/) but I am unable to understand what I should do to get the database design installed into my pgadmin III as shown in the video of the link, i.e., the [image view](http://s14.postimg.org/4b2m0ye7l/database.png).

I'm confused whether to make any installations, or is it like an Addon? I'm confused about what to do.

I need some support on how to make this work so that I can make an ER-diagram by using pgadmin III.

Comment: I haven't used pgadmin in ages, but back then the diagram functionality was built-in. Perhaps it has moved or something like that? Did you try all of the various buttons, check the manual, etc.?

Comment: @Denis I checked the [Community Guide for PostgreSQL GUI](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) but i am unable to find that.

Comment: I will sure check SchemaSpy :) Thanks for your suggestion @kmonsoor

Comment: you may try [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/). I have posted [a step-by-step guide for it](http://blog.kmonsoor.com/generate-er-diagram-from-sql-database/). SchemaSpy worth the shot.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to get that button to appear. But I've read the [Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) and found this [Valentina](http://www.valentina-db.com/valentina-studio-overview). Which supports forward/reverse engineering for PostgreSQL database. You can also try the similar products from the same page.

Alternatively you can try this [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/), here is an example of the [output](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/relationships.html). Note that higher level / raw ERD is impossible to be auto-generated as it is a subject of many different interpretations.

Here is a commercial alternative software to achieve a similar result: [DbVis](http://www.dbvis.com/).

Comment: As of May 2014 this is a great solution and even appears to beat pgAdmin3 on many fronts.

Comment: The folks from Valentina can't even spell PostgreSQL correctly - they use "Postgre" on their homepage. That sounds as if they don't really use Postgres that much.