# How to access the pgadmin database designer?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am running pgadmin 1.18.... In the options pane I can set the font for the database designer but I see absolutelly no way to access this db designer window, no icon or menu or whatsoever...

Is it a working feature under pgadmin 1.18?

Should it be enabled?

Comment: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/_images/gqb.png

Comment: Just create a new query and click on Graphical Query Builder tab.

Comment: Oups, perhaps duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694261/1216680

Comment: @JustBob, thank, that was it. I would have voted for your answer...

Comment: @Houari, not exactly the same question but definitelly related...

Comment: @Macario ok! so i just undeleted my answer

Answer (score 3):

Graphical Query builder :

[image: PG Admin Graphical Query builder]

[Source](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/gqb.html)

Comment: Why did you post the query builder when the OP asked for a database designer? Were there comments (since deleted) that changed the meaning of the question?

Answer (score 2):

PgAdmin 4 can generate the ERD from an existing database. Just right-click on the database and select Generate ERD (Beta). This is what helped me.

[image]